# python - how to get characters between specific characters which occur many times in a string

Tags: python

I have a string, which has around 270 M lines, as following;

```
<DOC> <DOC>+BDTag
<S> <S>+BSTag
--- ----
--- ----
</S> </S>+ESTag
<S> <S>+BSTag
--- ----
--- ----
</S> </S>+ESTag
<S> <S>+BSTag
--- ----
--- ----
</S> </S>+ESTag
-----
```

I want to get the characters between `<S> <S>+BSTag` and `</S> </S>+ESTag` in all string, and create a list of it.

Could you give me an example of a fastest solution?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution can be using regular expressions.

For example  using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) we can write,

```
>>> str = """<DOC> <DOC>+BDTag
... <S> <S>+BSTag
... hello world
... </S> </S>+ESTag
... <S> <S>+BSTag
... line 2
... </S> </S>+ESTag
... <S> <S>+BSTag
... line 3
... </S> </S>+ESTag
... -----"""

>>> re.findall(r'<S> <S>\+BSTag(.*?)</S> </S>\+ESTag', str, re.DOTALL)
['\nhello world\n', '\nline 2\n', '\nline 3\n']
```

---

**What it does?**

- `<S> <S>\+BSTag` Matches the start line.
- `(.*?)` The, `.*` matches anything. `?` makes it lazy so that it stops when it sees the first end line.
- `</S> </S>\+ESTag` Matches the end line
- `re.DOTALL` This is makes sure that the `.` matches new lines as well.